# Why 'eigen()' and 'fa.parallel()' give different eigenvalues?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, eigenvalues

I ran an EFA on 10 items in Rstudio. I did parallel analysis (`fa.parallel`) using `psych` package and also eigenvalues using these codes:
`correlation<-cor(), eigen(correlation)`. However, both of the results shown different eigenvalues. Why is that so?  Which eigenvalues should I refer to for exploratory factor analysis?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give more detail about your data and analysis. This example gives the same eigenvalues:

```
library(psych)

data(USArrests)
xcor <- cor(USArrests)

eigen(xcor)$values
[1] 2.4802416 0.9897652 0.3565632 0.1734301

fa.parallel(xcor, n.obs= nrow(USArrests))$pc.values
[1] 2.4802416 0.9897652 0.3565632 0.1734301
```